# Field to use when posting JSON objects containing a variable size array in Spring DTO?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate. I'm trying to create a DTO which will act as a `@ModelAttribute` binding when I post information from a form to my endpoint in my controller.

My information is coming in like this:

```
{ 
  "userId": 1239992, 
  "name": "Tanya", 
  "phones":[
    {"android": 212882939}, 
    {"iPhone": 12321321312}, 
    ... perhaps variable amounts more 
   ]
}
```

My thought is to capture it as such in a DTO:

```
public class ContactDTO {
   private int userId;
   private String name;
   private Map<String, Int> phones; // unsure of this. This would
   //hoping to produce a collection of phone type -> phone number 

   // getters and setters
}
```

And then in my controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/newContact")
public @ResponseBody ContactDTO createNewContact(@ModelAttribute ContactDTO newContact) {
   Map<String, int> allPhones = newContact.getPhones();

   //do stuff with the phones            
}
```

However, I have no idea if that actually binds. How do I go about collecting a variable amount of the same type of field where the amounts are set in the client side before being POST'ed back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to acheive this but the simplest way IMHO is the `POJO` way. As per your JSON your `phones` key is an array of objects.

Simply define another class `Contact` and use it as a composition in your `ContactDTO`.

`Contact` class

```
public class Contact {

   private String phoneType; //This better be an enum
   private String phoneNumber;

   //setters and getters

}
```

You can now have a `List<Contact>` in your `ContactDTO` like so

```
public class ContactDTO {

   private int userId;
   private String name;
   private List<Contact> phones; //Now you can have a variable number of phones in your JSON

   //setters and getters

}
```

Comment: If I do it this way - will `@ModelAttribute ContactDTO newContact` in the controller really be able to automatically make that binding? also `phoneType` is not an enum - need to allow people to write a custom tag for their phone type. `work iPhone` `family phone` etc.

Comment: This is actually the simplest and most easily manageable way you can handle it. Yes it definitely will bind your `phones` in the `ContactDTO` as long as you are passing in a list of phones in your `JSON` and you are binding it with `@RequestBody`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your json actually by default maps to

```
public class ContactDTO {
   private int userId;
   private String name;
   private List<Map<String, Integer>> phones; 
}
```

There are lots of ways you can approach this if you want single map

1. Custom deserializer
2. Pojo for phones, but your map would actually be a list like in [Abdullah Khan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660086/1032167)
3. Custom getter/setter (probably the easiest to implement if you want to keep `Map<String, Int>` and preserve json format).
   Here is demo:

   ```
   public static class ContactDTO {

       private int userId;
       private String name;
       private Map<String, Integer> phones; // USE Long and not Integer as value

       // getters/setters

       //for deserialization
       @JsonProperty("phones") 
       public void setPhonesFromLIist(List<Map<String,Int>> phones) {
           this.phones = new HashMap<>();
           phones.forEach(phone-> this.phones.putAll(phone));
       }

       //for serialization
       @JsonProperty("phones")
       public Set setPhonesAsLIist() {
           return phones.entrySet();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better if you could slightly change the format of the incoming JSON to:

```
{ 
  "userId": 1239992, 
  "name": "Tanya", 
  "phones": {
    "android": 212882939, 
    "iPhone": 12321321312
  }  
}
```

Then you can keep using the following POJO class (with the desired map):

```
class ContactDTO {
    private int userId;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Long> phones;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Note:** you need a Long to represent `12321321312`, because it's too large to fit in an Integer.

Comment: I possibly could keep the data type that way. The phone type will be "random" type (as in, I can't always count on it to have determined values - user may customize it) when it comes in through the JSON. If that's so, then it's fine? And noted on the use of Integer, I think I have it as BigInteger in my code, and may have just left that out.